# Do I need to pick up my checked luggage at Narita airport if I have an overnight layover?

Tags: luggage, layovers, nrt

When landing at Narita and, overnight 19 hours later flying out, will I be required to pick up my checked luggage?

Comment: Not if it's on a single ticket, but since you have to enter Japan anyway (the transit area closes at night) you could probably ask them to unload it. Why is this a concern?

Comment: Depends on the airline, not all will hold baggage that long.  Best to call the airline you are flying.

Comment: I wanted to explore during my layover since I land at 4pm. I just didn't know if I'm required to claim my baggage and if so where can I stow them to explore.

Comment: @Crazydre *"the transit area closes at night"* Source for this?

Comment: @fkraiem Timatic https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=jp&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=tw&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C "TWOW: Holders of onward tickets transiting on the
  same calendar day"

Comment: @Tori are you are on the same airline? Are you also flying out of Narita? Same ticket?

Comment: You will have to ask the Agent at check-in.  High probability yes, you will have to collect your luggage.